# Laravel 4 Artisan error when trying to install a bundle

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, bundle

I am simply trying to install a laravel bundle via the Artisan CLI using the latest Laravel 4 beta from github.

But when I try something like:

```
php artisan bundle:install bob
```

I'm confronted with

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
There are no commands defined in the "bundle" namespace.
```

I've had a look around online and can't seem to find a solution to this or even anyone else having similar problems for that matter.

Has anyone else experienced this error or any ideas on a solution?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you're using Laravel 4 (which based on the tags for this question, you are) then bundles are no longer used.

### Out with bundles, in with composer

Instead, Laravel 4 makes use of composer packages. It's kind of similar but at the same time very different in how it works. Here isn't the right place to explain all of composer, so check out the links below to find out more:

- [Getting started with Laravel 4](http://chris-schmitz.com/getting-started-with-laravel-4/)
- [How to setup Laravel 4](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-setup-laravel-4/)
- [Composer primer](http://daylerees.com/composer-primer)

### Laravel 4 Generator

Now, since you were asking about *bob*, the closest equivalent for the *bob bundle* would probably be Jeffrey Ways generator package, which you can learn more about here: [Laravel-4-Generators](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators)

Comment: ahh silly me.. of course it doesn't use bundles anymore :derp

Comment: I'm actually already using Jeffrey Way's Generator, I was initially looking to use this http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/facebook-sdk

Do you know if it would it work if I added this github repo to composer or does have to be on Packigist ?

I suspect it does :-'

@duellsy Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You should be able to use it, as long as the project has a composer.json file in it (which this does) you should be able to add it to your composer.json file, do a composer update, and it should come down. FYI it's located on packagist here anyway: https://packagist.org/packages/facebook/php-sdk

Comment: Is there a website listing packages for Laravel, like the bundles website?